# sql server - efficient way to update table from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

i need to update suppID column on ordersTB table from suppTB table. tables shown below:

**suppTB**

```
suppID ,suppName , itemID ,....
```

**ordersTB**

```
itemID, suppID(added later so mostly null's)...
```

what the most efficient way to update this table. i tried this query from old Q's here ([How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)) ,but it executing over a day and still running

```
UPDATE ordersTB
SET A.suppID = B.suppID
FROM  ordersTB as A
JOIN  suppTB as B
    ON A.itemID = B.itemID
WHERE A.suppID is null
```

*other notes & things i tried:*

- both tables are huge size (tens of millions)
- itemID & suppID columns are indexed. i remove the indexs before the update to make it faster. still take too long.
- also try MERGE query. same results..

Comment: Are you sure your SQL is correct? you're telling it you want to update ordersTB but this table/alias does not appear in the part of the query following the FROM

Comment: you right, my write here were worng, i just copy the correct query

Comment: Post your plan output. Also tell us whether the query works if you swap ``UPDATE... SET ...` for `SELECT * FROM

Comment: This begs the question - why do you keep the `suppId` in both tables? Isn't the `ItemId` enough to identify the correct `SuppId` for each item?

Comment: #Caius: my plan is very simple, to update table from another table. i will try your advise of testing the SELECT query after db will be available (still canceling the long lasting update query).; #Zohar: there is more columns on those tables that depends on it. also i need to update more tables this way so i curious what is the efficient way.  if this had only those tables and colunms you probablly right!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update large table with millions of rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903375/how-to-update-large-table-with-millions-of-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you really should strive to duplicate as little data as possible. Anything that's not used as a foreign key should be stored only on a single location. That might make select statements a little more cumbersome but ensures data integrity far better.

Answer (score 1):

Updating lots of rows is expensive.  The first thing to check is whether or not you are updating each row just once:

```
select s.item_ID, count(*)
from suppTB s
group by s.item_ID
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

If this is returning any rows, then you have multiple updates to the same row.  And that is a performance hit.  You should fix the business logic.  But you can put an arbitrary matching value in each row:

```
UPDATE o
SET suppID = s.suppID
FROM ordersTB o CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) s.*
      FROM suppTB s
      WHERE o.itemID = s.itemID
     )
WHERE o.suppID is null;
```

If this doesn't address the issue, you probably need to reload the table.  The logic is something like:

```
select . . . , -- all columns except suppId
       s.suppId
into temp_ordersTb
from ordersTb o left join
     suppTb s
     on o.itemID = s.itemID;

truncate table ordersTb;

insert into ordersTb (. . .)
    select . . .
    from temp_ordersTb;
```

Of course, be sure you backup your tables before attempting this!